How to take care of a "dynamic" object in an IF-ELSE-loop in C#?
I have the following C#-code:
while (...)
{
    ...(out var information);
    dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(information);

    if (obj.Some_Property != null)
    {

As you see, it creates an object, based on a string, called information.
But, that information sometimes is incomplete, so I need to split this function, and I arrive at this:
string partial_information = "";
dynamic obj;
while (...)
{
    ... (out information);
    
    if (partial_information == "")
    {
        try
        {
            obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(information);
        }
        catch (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException ex)
               // 'information' only contains the first part of the actual information
        {
            partial_information = information;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(partial_information + information);
                // in the previous loop, some 'information' was written to 'partial_information'.
                // Now the concatenation of both is used for deserialising the info.
        partial_information = ""; // don't forget to re-initialise afterwards
    }

    if (obj.Some_Property  != null) // <-- Compiler error (!!!)
    {

This, however, does not compile: the line if (obj.Some_Property  != null) generates a CS1065 compiler error: Use of unassigned local variable 'obj'.
In my opinion, this makes no sense, as obj is declared even outside of the whole while-loop.
How can I handle this?
Thanks in advance
P.s. I've already tried this, but this also does not work:
while (...)
{
    dynamic obj;
    ... (out information);


Initialize obj in your code: dynamic obj = null;

Suppose this is the first iteration of the while loop, and a JsonReaderException is caught in the catch block. You assign partial_information = information, but does not initialise obj. After that, the if...else completes, and we check if (obj.Some_Property  != null), but obj is still uninitialised What do you want to happen in this case?

@ValiMaties: thanks for your quick and correct reply, this compiles indeed.

@Sweeper: ... and you're also right: I added an extra null-check because indeed: when the information is not complete, obj does not exist and hence equals null.

"Does not exist" (aka not definitely assigned) is not "null". If you want that you should initialise it null at the start like Vali said, and you should also make the check null-safe. if (obj?.Some_Property != null)

You can also continue; in the catch block if there is nothing else to do in the loop.

@Sweeper: This is more or less what I've done (but I'm working with an extra explicit null-check if (obj != null) for readability reasons.

Who will write the solution as an answer? I'll accept it.
